# scalatest report contains $u0020 and $colon

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am using scalatest. The problem is that test report is difficult to read. Names of tests have replaced spaces with `$u0020`, `:` with `$colon` and so on.

For example the:

```
def `test: find '.gitignore' file on disk` = { 
    //...
}
```

... in report will look like:

`test$colon$u0020find$u0020$u0027$u002Egitignore$u0027$u0020file$u0020on$u0020disk`

How to prevent this?

Versions of scala and scalatests are:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10.0-M7" % "1.9-2.10.0-M7-B1" % "test"
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-M7"
```

**Edited**

Clue. I think that behind the scenes it uses `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()(depth)`.

Comment: What kind of report? surefire? CI server? Sonar?

Comment: I mean standard output appearing on console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you upgraded to Scala 2.10.0-M7, you accidentally downgraded from a ScalaTest 2.0 milestone release to ScalaTest 1.9. The pretty method names in back ticks isa ScalaTest 2.0 feature that was unavailable in ScalaTest releases prior to 2.0. You probably want to use a 2.0.M4 version of ScalaTest built for Scala 2.10.0-M7.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.0.M4-2.10.0-M7-B1" % "test"
scalaVersion := "2.10.0-M7"
```

You will also notice a deprecation warning about Suite's test methods, and they will likely still come out with the dollar signs in them even under 2.0.M4-2.10.0-M7-B1. That's because Suite was deprecated as a stye trait in 2.0.M4 in general. To get the pretty names back you'll need to port your Suite to Spec.

http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M4/#org.scalatest.Spec

Comment: Finally I migrated to FreeSpec. It is very flexible and easy to understand way to write/read tests.

Answer (score 4):

Consider extending [`FunSuite`](http://scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_suite) instead:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class SomeTest extends FunSuite {

    test("test: find '.gitignore' file on disk") {
        //..
    }

}
```